# How can I avoid image overflowing its container?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I've tried researching this problem and asking someone more experienced than I am with CSS styling, but we couldn't find a solution. Here is the JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/haha78sr/.

The image with the id,

> ctl00_cphBody_btnFile or btnFile

is overflowing the body, and I want it to be floating up in the body, one row *below* the repeater of folders (even if the folders do not always fill a row). It should also be aligned horizontally with the other items above it (the folder items).

```
<div class="" style="padding: 10px; width: 150px; height: 150px;">
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnFile" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/joshTest/cat1.png"
                Style="border-width: 0px; width: 150px; height: 150px;"/>
```

EDIT: Here is an image of what it looks like for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI7DS.jpg
This is after setting the attribute "margin-left: 36px" to the div displayed in code above. So, this helps a little bit, but it's not completely what I want. I am curious as to why that should be able to help because the back and forward buttons (seen in the screen) have a large height to avoid anything going towards the edge like the div above was doing.

Comment: You jsfiddle is not showing any images because the images are not hosted online, so it's hard to see what you mean. Generally, you can prevent overflowing by putting `overflow:hidden` on the parent element, but I'm not sure what the end result should look like in your case. Can you add a sketch to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to change the picture to another picture in your fiddle and messed around with it.
Got it to work how i think you want i to work with this code:

```
<input id="ctl00_cphBody_btnFile" type="image" style="border-width: 0px; width: 150px; height: 150px; position: absolute;" src="http://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/d4g_logo_global.jpg" name="ctl00$cphBody$btnFile">
```

What i did was adding `position:absolute;` to the elements style.

It might not be the neatest sulution but it was the quicket i could find.

Comment: That helps a lot, but now I still need to figure out how to display the images side-by-side just like for the folders. I tried copying and pasting the same image in that div, but the second image displays below the first image.

Comment: Im not realy sure how you mean but would `display: inline-block;` help?
Mabye you can modify your fiddle to show your new problem?
Also, dont forget to upvote if it's helpful for you :)

Comment: Actually, "display: inline-block" seems to put the first image in the correct position by itself, even without the "position:absolute", so that's really helpful. It doesn't fix my next image not displaying how I want, but that answers my original question. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :)
Here is a version of the fiddle that might be what you are looking for if i understood you correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/haha78sr/2/